# treeview checkbox: how to check on select and vice versa

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm working on a `TreeView` with its `CheckBoxes` property set to `True`. I want the same functionality as in a `CheckListBox` in that if I check the box of a `TreeNode`, that node will be selected; and if I select a node, that node's checkbox will be checked.  I'm not sure what event I need to hookup to do this.  Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    treeView1.SelectedNode.Checked = true;
}
```

This `Event` is tied to the `TreeView`s `AfterSelect` event

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if you keep clicking on one node, it'll only select it the very first time, and never unselect it when it's clicked again.

Comment: Then just overwrite the onclick event as well to take care of that